# how to disable jquery data function return value by ref?

Tags: jquery, pass-by-reference, jquery-data

somehow getting jquery `data()` function return an object by ref.

it is a way in javascript to point to the object him self without to modify the ref object ?

here is my demonstration of the problem :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var  c= console.log ;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var _data   = $("#elem").data();
    var _xdata = _data ; // should be a miror object 
    console.log($("#elem").data() );
    _xdata.id = "changes applied back to #elem.data object !!!"  ;
    console.log($("#elem").data() );
    //any way to separate between $("#elem").data() and _xdata ??
}) ;
</script>
<div id="elem" data-id="1" data-foo="some data"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a jQuery issue - its a javascript one. When you're assigning _xdata to _data, you're actually assigning the value of the reference to the _data object (a touch confusing I know). If you'd like to create a "mirror object", you should clone it like:

```
var _xdata = jQuery.extend(true, {}, _data);
```

EDIT: 
I'm always too slow here, but if you're looking for a shallow copy you could go with:

```
var _xdata = jQuery.extend({}, _data);
```

Comment: this is not javascript issue its jquery try without  cloning the object just getting the object not by reference :
// should be a cloned object \n
var _data   = $("#elem").data(); \n
_data.id = "changes applied back to #elem.data object !!!"  ;\n
console.log($("#elem").data() );

Comment: Well if you'd like to manipulate the _data variable, you can make a copy of it (not the whole element, just the object you're getting retuned from data() ) and then you'll be fine.

Comment: anyway this solved my problem `var _data  = jQuery.extend({},$("#elem").data());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's .clone() method to clone the object (and it's data), instead of creating a reference as you're doing now.

```
var _xdata = $("#elem").clone(true).data();
```

That way you can manipulate the cloned data without affecting the original.

Comment: true ! but clone will clone the element itself and in my project it mean to clone a very large element (with a lot of sub elements , events etc) sorry .. this is not optimized solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is, values from data-whatever are stored in internal cache upon page load.
So when you write `$("#something").data("whatever")` it returns value from the time page was loaded regardless of the data-whatever value written in html in that specific moment.